# What is the most efficient algorithm for storing and printing character, frequency pairs?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

Describe the MOST efficient (in the worst case big O) algorithm, and required data structures to determine the frequencies of characters in an English text document that can have any character on the keyboard, with upper or lower case for letters, and print the (character, frequencies) pairs at the end. What operations would you count for worst case, and give the resulting big O time.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. What difficulty do you have solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use an array of size equal to 256 ( total ascii characters ).
Initially all values in array are 0. While reading characters from English text document , we can simply increment the value in index equal to the ascii value of given characters. Hence, these operations can be done in `O(1)` time compleixty without any overhead ( if we use hashMap, we will have overhead for collision in worst case ).
As we have to loop over all characters in given text document, the overall time complexity of proposed method will be `O(n)` , where n is the length of text document.

Answer (score 0):

A hashmap where key=character and value=frequency would work best for any kind of characters and encodings.

If you only need whatever a keyboard can produce, you can also use a frequency array where F[character ASCII code]=frequency.

Both solutions have a constant O(1) runtime per operation.